# Can someone break this perl expression and explain it for me

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to filter data that has quotes as well as a comma in the fields. I came across this expression this and it worked, but could not understand. Kindly help.

```
perl -nle 's/".*?"//g;print s/,//g+1' file
```

Comment: @nYuker_98 D - [s](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/msixpodualngcer)

Answer (score 2):

`perl -nle` means something like:

```
-l turns on auto-chomping and adds a new-line to the output
-n loops the program over the complete file
-e makes perl expect an execute-string
```

So, `s/".*?"//g;print s/,//g+1` is executed for every line in the file.

That is two parts:`s/".*?"//g;` substitutes `".*?"` with an empty string, effectively removes that part from the string.

- `"` is litteral `"`
- `.*` is a series of zero or more characters
- `?` makes the `.*` non greedy.

So it will remove texts like `"Is it a plain, or a car?"`.

The second part `print s/,//g+1`:

- `s/,//g` means substitute all `,` with an empty string. The expression returns the number of substitutions that it makes.
- `+1` adds 1 to the number of substitutions done.
- And `print` prints that number. Because of the `-l`, there is a new-line after the number.

So, `"Is it a plain, or a car?" yes!` will print 1, `"Is it a plain, or a car?" Perhaps, maybe.` will print 2.

Comment: Great write up. The .*? is to make the match non-greedy https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Quantifiers

Comment: *`?` is litteral `?`* - No, it's not. It makes the preceding `.*` non-greedy.